# Unable to access static variables from NSObject class but I am able from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

Ok, strange thing occurred and I guess answer is quite simple, but I fail to figure out what's going on.

Situation is next:

I have an NSObject class called Constants.

Constants.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>

@interface Constants : NSObject

+(Constants*)shared;

@property GTLPlusPerson* googlePlusUser;
@property int profileType;
@property NSString *userName, *userLastName, *userEmail,    *userGoogleId,*userProfilePicture;

@end
```

Constants.m

```
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation Constants

@synthesize profileType, userProfilePicture, userLastName,userName,userGoogleId,userEmail;

static Constants *constants = nil;

+ (Constants*)shared {

if (nil == constants) {

   constants = [[Constants alloc] init];

}
return constants;
}
```

I use this class in order to save some static variables that I will use throughout the app.

Now, If I try and declare one of the variables like

```
[Constants shared].userName = @"name";
```

from an NSObject class method (Which I call from a ViewController), I fail to do so.
But If I declare Constant variables directly from ViewController (after viewDidLoad for example) everything works fine.

Here is the Class I try to declare variables from, but I fail (It also has singleton in it, that might be the source of the problem, but im not sure why would it)

```
@implementation GoogleLogin

static GoogleLogin* gLogin = nil;

+(GoogleLogin*)shared
{

if (nil == gLogin){
    gLogin = [[[self class]alloc]init];
}
return gLogin;


}


-(void)getProfile
{
GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
plusService.retryEnabled = YES;
[plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];
GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
plusService.apiVersion=@"v1";

[plusService executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLPlusPerson *person,
                            NSError *error) {
            if (error){
                NSLog(@"Error while fetching user profile: %@", error);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"User profile information fetched OK");
                [Constants shared].googlePlusUser = person;
                [Constants shared].profileType = 1;
                [Constants shared].userName = person.name.givenName;
                [Constants shared].userLastName = person.name.familyName;
                [Constants shared].userEmail = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail;
                [Constants shared].userGoogleId = person.identifier;
                [Constants shared].userProfilePicture = person.image.url;



                NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ ",person.name.givenName,person.name.familyName,[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail,person.identifier,person.image.url);

            }
}];
}
```

and this is how I call those methods, from my ViewController:

```
 - (IBAction)signupWithGoogle:(UIButton *)sender {

//if i call this method here, on button click, it will finish all the steps needed, except setting constant variables
[[GoogleLogin shared] googleLoginFromViewController:self];

//if I uncomment next line, username will be declared and I will be able to access it later
//[Constants shared].userName = @"Petar";

}
```

Can anybody figure out why is this happening and what should I do to change that?

Answer (score 2):

When you define a property is strongly suggested to declare the attributes to use with it. I guess the compiler should complain about this with a message like

> No 'assign', 'retain', or 'copy' attribute is specified - 'assign' is
>   assumed

So, use the following instead (`copy` semantics is fine for mutable classes).

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
```

You should also specify if the property should be accessed in a `atomic` or `nonatomic` way. If you don't specify it, the former will be applied.

Then, you are using a singleton pattern. The suggested way is to use GCD like so.

```
+ (ConstantsManager*)sharedManager {

    static ConstantsManager *sharedManager;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. I already mentioned that this setup works if l set propreties directly from view controller, so it shouldn't and it doesn't make ay difference

Comment: If I set some constant variable from GoogleLogin class, for example [Constants shared.userName = @"aaa" and try to read that variable from some other ViewController later on, I get null as result. But, If i set that same variable from any ViewController, I am able to set it right and read it later on.

Comment: Try to use `copy` and let me know the results.

Answer (score 1):

Well you did not set your property attributes on the singleton class. 
For example,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) ...
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. I already mentioned that this setup works if l set propreties directly from view controller, so it shouldn't and it doesn't make ay difference

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the property assignments out of the `completionHandler`? It may be that your properties are being assigned on a background thread and your view controller is not catching the assignment. An easy way to check is to override the setters and getters and put breakpoints in them to see what order they are being accessed.

1) Remove the `@synthesize` because it's not needed (properties will be synthesized as _property automatically)

2) Override setter & getter

```
-(void)setProfileType:(NSInteger)profileType {
    _profileType = profileType;
}

-(NSInteger)profileType {
    return _profileType;
}
```

3) Place breakpoints within these methods and see if the getter is being called before the setter. Alternatively, if simply moving the assignments out of the `completionHandler` fixes it you know you have some concurrency issues.

I suggest reading up on `atomic/nonatomic` properties, `@synthesize` and Objective-C concurrency.